# Typescript lazy type resolve (resolve specific type after declaring any)

Tags: typescript

How to make type resolving in such case?

I have following interfaces:

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
}

interface TestSettings<T, IdT> {
    setId: (t: T) => IdT;
    getId: (t: IdT) => void;
}
```

And following code:

```
let settings: TestSettings<Item, any> = {
    setId: x => x.id,
    getId: x => x     <--- Here 'x' type is 'any' but it is possible to have type 'number'? 
};
```

Is there possibility in Typescript to get such typechecks without obviously setting them in interface declarations?

Answer (score 0):

> Here 'x' type is 'any'

You explicitly asked it to be `any` with `TestSettings<Item, any>`.

## Fix

> but it is possible to have type 'number'?

Sure:

```
let settings: TestSettings<Item, number> = {
    setId: x => x.id,
    getId: x => x
};
```

Comment: Of course I know of such possibility but want to make type definition without explicitly indication number. I know that in some cases it is possible.

Comment: Not in this case 

Comment: But it could or you disagree? After declaring 'setId: x => x.id' Typescript could know with which type we are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the type `T` always has an `id` property of the appropriate type, you can define `TestSettings` like this:

```
interface TestSettings<T extends { id: any }> {
    setId: (t: T) => T['id'];
    getId: (t: T['id']) => void;
}
```

If you need inference, unfortunately TypeScript does not try to [infer optional generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400).  If it did, you'd be able to `TestSettings<T, IdT = any>` and then it might do what you want if you declare `let settings: TestSettings<Item>`.  As it is now, you either need to specify the whole thing as @basarat says, or you can try to have it infer the whole thing:

```
let settings = {
    setId: (x:Item) => x.id,
    getId: (x:number) => {}
}; // you have to really specify this
declare function doSomethingWithTestSettings<T, IdT>(ts: TestSettings<T, IdT>): void;
doSomethingWithTestSettings(settings); //infers as TestSettings<Item, number>
```

which might be worse for you.  So, you're probably just going to have to explicitly annotate it, sorry.